# Cross Domain Tracking set up in GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager, tag-manager

I am trying to set up cross domain tracking for my company and I think I have most of it down except for a couple of questions regarding the modification of the GA Universal tag.  When I click on "Cross Domain Tracking" under "Fields To Set" I have three options.  I understand I have to put the Cross Domain Tracking variable I created under "Auto Link Domains".  But what do I put under "Use Hash Delimiter" and "Decorate Forums"?  I don't even know what these two things mean much less what I should select for their values.  All I want to do is make sure all of the traffic for the myriad of domains we have is reported under one account.  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In instances where urls already have parameters appended, they are usually appended with a ?

```
somepage.html?param1=param1val&param2=param2val
```

"Use Hash Delimiter" set to true allows the linker parameter to be added via a # which is useful where there are parameters already appended to the url or where some setups strip parameters appended with a ?

```
somepage.html?param1=param1val&param2=param2val#_ga=1.199239214.1624002396.1440697407
```

(It is the equiv of useAnchor in the autoLink method when configuring the analytics.js tracking code snippet.)

"Decorate Forums" is set to true when needing to add a linker parameter to form submissions that point to destinations matching the domain parameter.

[GA Dev Documenation for autolink method and parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/linker#automatically_adding_linker_parameters)